# Random order with distinct column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am creating a query which involves several joins, which causes some duplicates

```
@users = User.joins(...).where(...).select("users.id")
```

From that result I want to make the records `distinct` and in `RANDOM()` order

I can't seem to recreate that with activerecord.

With SQL it would look something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.*
from ( long complex query)
ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

Comment: I am not grabbing all users, and I am limiting the query afterwards. Shuffling would be terribly slow. All I want is to order by RANDOM() with a setseed, but I either get duplicates, or I get an error saying I can't order by random if I don't select the random column. Selecting the random() column makes the row not distinct...

Comment: yes but that would require me to select the RANDOM() column to order by it, which would make it not distinct

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest things to do, rather than building complex queries in any framework, is to build the complex query with standard SQL and then wrap it in a view:

```
CREATE VIEW complex_stuff AS
  SELECT DISTINCT users.*
  FROM ( long complex query)
  ORDER BY RANDOM();
```

The view becomes a simple entity or class from which you pull the required columns, possibly filtering by some column (`SELECT a, b, c FROM complex_stuff WHERE d = ?`).

Comment: not familiar with VIEW in SQL or if its possible to do it with activerecord. Can you link me something to read about this?

Comment: A view is like a stored `SELECT` statement. You use it just like you would any other table. In effect, you make the effort of designing a complex query once, then use it repeatedly. It is much more efficient than doing this in ror because the query plan is stored in PostgreSQL. You can read up on views [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-views.html).

Comment: Also, your ror code will become much cleaner and easier to maintain. In general, you should let PostgreSQL do what it is designed for: storing data and processing it in possibly complex queries, and use Ruby where it excels: presenting data to the user.